# Unable to debug logic app using VSCode trigger is Event Grid

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-logic-apps

I have logic app with `Event Grid as Trigger`

[image]

I have VSCode and exported this logic app locally.

I'm trying to debug / run this logic app locally passed connection string in local setting in VSCode.

But still after doing `Azurite:Start` when click on debug button getting error -

Can anyone help me how we can debug/run logic app using VSCode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me how we can debug/run logic app using VSCode.

To Debug the error follow the steps below:

When we export the logic apps we are given option to deploy connections, It mentioned the required steps to follow.

> **Note :** To run the Logic apps locally You need to have installed [`Azure Function core tools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows,isolated-process,node-v4,python-v2,http-trigger,container-apps&pivots=programming-language-powershell#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools), `.NET 6` and `Node.js`

- **By selecting `Deploy managed connection`:**

  It  creates a connection in the resourcegroup you selected or creted new.

  [image]
- **without selecting `Deploy managed connection`:**

  1. you need to deploy the connection manually using the template json file `LogicAppStandardConnections.template.json` created inside the `.development\deployment` folder.
  2. you need to add the parameters value of `RuntimeUrl` and `RawAuthKey` in template file's `parameters` section.

  ```
  "azureeventgrid-std-RuntimeUrl": {
    "type": "String",
    "defaultValue": "https://5205eaf6cc9b25ed.09.common.logic-australiaeast.azure-apihub.net/apim/azureeventgrid/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "azureeventgrid-std-Auth": {
    "type": "String",
    "defaultValue": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
  ```

  3. Open `Azure Portal-> Search Deploy a custom template`.

  [image]

  4. Select `Build your own template in the editor`

  [image]

  5. Add you code directly or you can also upload you file and `save`.

  [image]

  6. `Name` is not required. Click `review+create`

  [image]
- **Open Designer in VSCode.**

You will need to delete the connectors which require connections. Such as `When a resource event occurs` and create it again and select `change connection` option at bottom.

- At First you will see it as invalid

[image]

- Open the deployed connection in Azure portal -> Edit Api Connection -> Authorize and Save

[image]

- You will now see connection as active and have option to select it

[image]

> **Note :** You need to Create connectors again and Authorize each connections, if you have Multiple connectors which requires connections.

#### `Run/Debug`

[image]

**For Refernce for Exporting logic apps Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/export-from-consumption-to-standard-logic-app).**

**For Custom template deployment check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal).**